# How to reset webform field validation state?

Tags: webforms

Not sure if I'm asking the question correctly. Here is the configuration:

- I have a form that contains conditionally hidden fields.
- The conditionally hidden webform fields are marked required.
- On the "condition", I've selected "clear values when hidden".

[image]
[image]

#### Repro steps

##### Step 1

Navigate to the page with the form. The form is initially displayed, the field (a checkbox) upon which the condition is contingent is defaulted to `unchecked` and the hidden fields are hidden - as expected.

###### Step 2 (first open)

I check the "*I need student license"* (the contingency field)...
The contingent fields now are displayed correctly.

###### Step 3

Uncheck the "*I need student license*" (the contingency field)...
The contingent fields are hidden - again, as expected.

###### Step 4 (2nd open)

I check the "*I need student license"*  field the **second time** and...
now the contingent fields are highlighted in red indicating a validation error.

#### Illustrated sequence

The sequence is illustrated in the graphic below.

Question is, how can I restore the fields under "Course Level" to the initial set every time the "I need student license" check box is checked (e.g., changes state from unset to set). Unless I'm missing something, I don't see any options that might "fix" the behavior on the backend/configuration side. I'm guessing this will have to be a frontend javascript solution.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should add/remove the required attribute together with the hidden/show option on the conditional field, instead of set required to the field.

e.g. if you check the postgraduate and the Faculty/Department is required, you set the conditional to display the field AND make it required. On this way, when you "reset" the form, the required attribute isn't there.

There's another way but you need to put the hands in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I tried what I believe you suggested. No luck. 
Would you mind connecting and discussing other options (or let me know if I missed something in the configuration). 
One thing I did was simplify the problem. e.g, I spun up a new instance of d9 with only `webform` and `Clientside Validation` enabled.